# Default state aria-pressed state of button on auto-playing video

Tags: button, accessibility, wai-aria

Just a general question around some decorative videos that auto-play when a user visits the page, along with buttons that pause/play them. I'm just wondering what the load state of the aria-pressed attribute should be when the user visits the page.

The user hasn't interacted with the button yet so technically aria-pressed state would be false, but since the video is already playing is it wrong to have the aria-pressed state set to true.

I can see arguments for both but want to make it as intuitive to screen-reader users as I can. Thanks for your insights.

```
<button aria-label="Pause video" aria-pressed="true" class="btn-clean">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I find out a pressed button with the label "Pause" as in your example code, to me it means that the video is currently paused.
Whether I have already interacted with the button or not doesn't change anything to my perception, and in fact the pressed state has nothing to do with  the fact to have already interacted with the button or not.

To make things clear in all cases, you should do one of the two following things upon changing the playing/paused state of the video, but not both:

- Change the state pressed or not, but never change the label
- Change the label, but never change the state pressed or not

In the first case, you will ahve "play, pressed" when the video is playing, and "play, not pressed" when the video isn't playing.

IN the second case, you will have "pause" when the video is playing, and "play" when the video isn't playing.

Notice how changing both the label and the pressed state makes things unclear, and in particular how "pause, pressed" is especially unclear.

Bonus note: The same reflection applies to an expand/collapse or show/hide button.

Comment: @QuentineC thank you for your insights. I can understand the confusion this way for sure. What you said make sense to me.